# populate en un campo de un array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Estoy tratando de hacer un populate() en el campo de un array no se si esto sea posible mi modelo Publicacion esta asi:

```
comentarios:[{autor : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Usuario }],contenido:String}],
```

lo que quiero es que cuando haga la consulta Publicacion.find().populate() que se llene el campo autor del array comentarios con la informacion  correspondiente